# JSON parsing in C# - extract a string array to another array

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I have a JSON string returned from an API and it has 1 field - ApiErrorMessage and an array - BlogCategoryList

```
entry = "{\"ApiErrorMessage\":null,\"BlogCategoryList\": 
[{\"BlogCategoryId\":2,\"BlogCategoryDescr\":\"To Start\"}, 
{\"BlogCategoryId\":1,\"BlogCategoryDescr\":\"Introduction\"}, 
{\"BlogCategoryId\":1,\"BlogCategoryDescr\":\"Introduction\"}]}"
```

In need to extract out that JSON string array to a variable that just has that JSON string array (it should look like below). As as I need to pass it along to be deserialized.

```
{"BlogCategoryList":
   [{"BlogCategoryId":2,"BlogCategoryDescr":"To Start"}, 
   {"BlogCategoryId":1,"BlogCategoryDescr":"Introduction"}, 
   {"BlogCategoryId":1,"BlogCategoryDescr":"Introduction"}]
}
```

---

```
public class BlogCategoryResult
{
    public BlogCategoryResult()
    {
        this.BlogCategoryList = new List<BlogCategory>();
    }

    public string ApiErrorMessage { get; set; }        
    public List<BlogCategory> BlogCategoryList { get; set; }
}
```

My code. Just not sure how to extract it.

```
   // Note: entry is a string type.
   var entry = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

   // I tried this, but the result is not correct.
   string[] resultArray = entry.Split('[');

   // I tried this, I get the list but then I get 'Can not convert Array to String' on the last command where I do the cast.
   JObject o = JObject.Parse(entry);
   string name = (string)o["ApiErrorMessage"];                        
   JArray list = (JArray)o["BlogCategoryList"];
   string listofentries = (string)list;

   // Deserializing the response (just the list) received from web api and storing into a model.  
   blogCategoryResult.BlogCategoryList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BlogCategory>>
   (listofentries);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should deserialize the entire json by passing the `BlogCategoryResult` class between the `<` and `>` of `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, and the whole `entry` variable in the `(` and `)`, after that you can easily pick the `BlogCategoryList` property

```
var entry = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
blogCategoryResult.BlogCategoryList = JsonConvert
    .DeserializeObject<BlogCategoryResult>(entry)
    .BlogCategoryList;
```

Comment: I already have a similar class. I included it above. I just need to extract that list from 'entry' as it will be eventually be passed to a view.

Comment: sorry I didn't view your edit. So you can deserialize the json as ```BlogCategoryResult``` and pick the ```BlogCategoryList``` property